# Kubectl commands cannot be executed from another VM

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

I'm having an issue when executing the "kubectl" commands. In fact, my cluster consists of one Master and one Worker node. The kubectl commands can be executed from the Master server without having an issue. But, I also have another VM which I use that VM as a Jump server to login to the  master and worker nodes. I need to execute the kubectl commands from that Jump server. I created the .kube directory, and copied the kubeconfig file from the Master node to the Jump server. And also I set the context correctly as well. But the kubectl commands hangs when executing from the Jump server and it gives a timeout error.

Below are the information.

```
kubectl config view
apiVersion: v1
clusters:
- cluster:
    certificate-authority-data: DATA+OMITTED
    server: https://10.240.0.30:6443
  name: kubernetes
contexts:
- context:
    cluster: kubernetes
    user: kubernetes-admin
  name: kubernetes-admin@kubernetes
current-context: kubernetes-admin@kubernetes
kind: Config
preferences: {}
users:
- name: kubernetes-admin
  user:
    client-certificate-data: REDACTED
    client-key-data: REDACTED

ubuntu@ansible:~$ kubectl config use-context kubernetes-admin@kubernetes
Switched to context "kubernetes-admin@kubernetes".

ubuntu@ansible:~$ kubectl get pods
Unable to connect to the server: dial tcp 10.240.0.30:6443: i/o timeout

ubuntu@ansible:~$ kubectl config current-context
kubernetes-admin@kubernetes
```

Everything seems to be OK for me and wondering why kubectl commands  hang when wxecuting from the  Jump server.

Comment: do you have any proxy set on jumpserver ``` echo $http_proxy && echo $https_proxy``` .

Comment: Can the jump machine ping `10.240.0.30`? Can it connect (e.g. telnet) to `6443`?

Comment: @confusedgenius, I executed the command which you shared. It doesn't give any output. Which means it doesn't have any proxy set.

Comment: @DazWilkin, From the Jump VM, I also can't telnet to the Master Node. telnet 10.240.0.30:6443
telnet: could not resolve 10.240.0.30:6443/telnet: Name or service not known

Comment: Port 6443 in Master node is not closed? If closed, from the Master node itself, I should not be able to execute the kubectl commands right?

Comment: The telnet command requires a space between the host and port: `telnet 10.240.0.30 6443`

Comment: @DazWilkin well it gives "Connection Timed Out"  telnet 10.240.0.30 6443
Trying 10.240.0.30...
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection timed out
Which means I have to open port 6443 in the Kubernetes Master Node? But the  Kubernetes Master node itself can telnet 127.0.0.1 6443 ?

Comment: ubuntu@master:~$ telnet 127.0.0.1 6443
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to 127.0.0.1 This is the output I get from the Kubernetes Master Node

Comment: This strongly suggests that the master is inaccessible from the other VM. You will need to resolve that issue. Good luck!

Comment: I was able to sort out the  issue using the Public IP address of the Kubernetes Master Node. Additionally, I opened port 6443 from any source (0.0.0.0/0) Telnet is success when I specifically use the Public IP address

Comment: But again another issue! When I execute the kubectl commands, now it gives Unable to connect to the server: x509: certificate is valid for 10.96.0.1, 10.240.0.30, not 35.189.5.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Troubleshooted the issue by verifying whether the Jump VM can telnet to Kubernetes Master Node by executing the below.

```
telnet <ip-address-of-the-kubernetes-master-node> 6443
```

Since the error was a **"Connection Timed Out"** I had to add a firewall rule to Kubernetes Master node. Added a firewall rule as below. **Note:** In my case I'm using GCP.

```
gcloud compute firewall-rules create allow-kubernetes-apiserver \
  --allow tcp:22,tcp:6443,icmp \
  --network kubernetes \
  --source-ranges 0.0.0.0/0
```

Then I was able to telnet to the Master Node without any issue. If still you can't get connected to the Master node, change the Internal IP in the kubconfig file under .kube directory to the Public IP address of the Master node.

Then change the context using below command.

```
kubectl config set-context <context-name>
```